# How to use Friendly URLs?

Tags: php, mysql, url, url-rewriting

I've been working on a little piece of php script that took me several days (I'm a noob)

Here's my code :

```
<?php
require ('connect.php');

$requete = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id="'.$_GET['id'].'"') or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($requete)=='0'){
}else{
    while($resultats = mysql_fetch_array($requete)){ 
?> <!-- some html content --> <?php
    }
}

mysql_close(); 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This script retrieves the content from my database, according to the ID.

> http: //localhost/mysite/video/atest.php?id=1

I'd like to know which kind of url rewriting i'd have to use in order to retrieve some keywords. I'd like to have that kind of URL:

> http: //localhost/mysite/video/1-first-video-title

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|png|jpe?g|gif|js|mp3|3gp|ico)$
RewriteRule atest/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)-([0-9]+) atest.php?id=$1&url=$2[L,QSA]
```

Went something wrong?

I'd also like to use that, but I get nothing shown on the screen (this page cannot be found).

```
if($resultats["url"]!=$_GET["url"]) {
  header ("location:/mysite/video/".$resultats["url"]."-".$resultats["id"]);
}
```

It searches in my table where it finds the URL keywords.

Thank you!

Comment: Hmm.. I didn't know that "Thank" was a PHP keyword.

Comment: It's like throw, but instead of an exception you get a page full of kittens.

Comment: Not to be confused with `Spank` which gets you a whole different page.

Comment: you need to write code that interpret friendly url into id.  you can't just link to it and then expect the script to understand on its own. beside watch out for putting $_GET directly into query, that's a big security hole right there.  validate it use (int) and for textual values use mysql real escape string function

Comment: Welcome to the beautiful world of SQL Injection! Your site can be hacked without a lot of effort. I understand you are a noob, so this is the best time to forget about the old `mysql_` functions while it's still not too late! If you are learning anyways, learn mysqli or PDO prepared statements instead, and make the world a happier place.

Comment: Use [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) not `mysql`.

Comment: Example of SQL Injection Attack (***WARNING:*** This example will delete your *entire* `videos` table. Use at own risk.): `http://localhost/mysite/video/atest.php?id="; DROP TABLE videos; "`

Comment: Hi Guys,

Thank you.

What should I use in order to get rid of the security issues? 
I've learnt about mysqli and PDO, but if I'll have to edit my code and enhance this with news more secured features, it will take me a while to do this...

Comment: How I can I protect my script with the latest features of mysql?

Comment: Trifonoff, it does not work, my database is always there :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here may actually be very simple: the RewriteRule is capturing variables the wrong way round `RewriteRule atest/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)-([0-9]+) atest.php?id=$1&url=$2[L,QSA]` will match "atest/example-42" and map it to "atest.php?id=example&url=42" - $1 referring to the first set of brackets, and $2 to the second. Try a `print_r()` or `var_export()` of `$_GET`

Incidentally, that regex may go wrong in some edge cases, because it doesn't assert that the ID has to come at the very end - so "atest/example-2-word-42" could end up picking out the ID as 2, not 42. Adding a "$" should fix that: `RewriteRule atest/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)-([0-9]+)$ atest.php?id=$1&url=$2 [L,QSA]`

If the rewrite rule just isn't working at all (your question isn't clear what the result is) it could be some subtlety in Apache's .htaccess handling...